# FF 57.0 - Conversion rate is 100 times lower than other versions but not null

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, e-commerce

For all FireFox versions since 57.0 (57.0, 58.0, 59.0), the conversion rate is 100 times lower than other versions. But not null.

The other events are working properly.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the exact same problem and I'm pretty sure this the reason:

Since version 57 firefox implemented a "feature" that delays the loading of the tracking script until other scripts on your page are loaded (https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/21/firefox-57-delays-tracking-domains/). This delay can take up to 6 seconds. So if your tracking a sale/goal on a confirm page. The user might leave your website before your gtm or ga code is being loaded and therefore your missing the conversion.

So far there doesn't seem to be an easy solution besides working on the loading performance on your conversion/sale page.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the answer. My page only appears for a second.